# How to disable scroll up?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I want to disable scroll up in my html document. How i can do that?
i don't want to use this way:

```
$(window).load(function(){
            var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
            var _direction;
            var _stopScroll = true;
            $(window).scroll(function(event){
                var _cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
                if(_top < _cur_top)
                {
                    _direction = 'down';
                }
                else
                {

                    $( "body" ).scrollTop(90); //scroll up
                }
                _top = _cur_top;
                console.log(_direction);
            });
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: why you don't want to use that way?

Comment: Do you mean you want to restrict the user to scroll up?

Comment: #putvande Yes. I want toggle scroll up.

Comment: only scroll up , not scroll down? or you want to disable scrollbars from document?

Comment: i want Only scroll down, not scroll up!